# ggtern error -> error-geom-point-requires-the-following-missing-aesthetics-x-and-y

Tags: r, ggplot2

There seems to be an issue with ggtern running with the new ggplot2. I have tried to load earlier versions of R, ggtern, and ggplot2 but cannot get them working. With the latest versions I get the following error:

Error: geom_point requires the following missing aesthetics: x and y

```
rlang::last_error()
<error/rlang_error>
geom_point requires the following missing aesthetics: x and y
Backtrace:

(function (x, ...) ...
ggtern:::print.ggplot(x)
ggtern:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
ggtern:::by_layer(function(l, d) l$compute_geom_1(d))
ggtern:::f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
l$compute_geom_1(d)
ggplot2:::f(..., self = self)
ggplot2:::check_required_aesthetics(...)

rlang::last_trace()
<error/rlang_error>
geom_point requires the following missing aesthetics: x and y
Backtrace:
x

+-(function (x, ...) ...
-ggtern:::print.ggplot(x)
+-ggtern::ggplot_build(x)
-ggtern:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)

\-ggtern:::by_layer(function(l, d) l$compute_geom_1(d))

  \-ggtern:::f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])

    \-l$compute_geom_1(d)

      \-ggplot2:::f(..., self = self)

        \-ggplot2:::check_required_aesthetics(...)
```

I have also tried loading ggtern before ggplot2 and loaded earlier versions of each package and R and RStudio.

Help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

ggtern is not compatible with the latest version of ggplot2. You should use the version 3.2.1 (or maybe version 3.3.0)

```
require(devtools)
install_version("ggplot2", version = "3.2.1", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

If you need other packages of tidy verse you will have to load them separately.

Comment: When I try to run install_version I get:   

> install_version("ggplot2", version = "3.2.1", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")

Error in install_version("ggplot2", version = "3.2.1", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org") : 
  could not find function "install_version" 

If I try an earlier version of the package from cran:

Warning in install.packages :

  package ‘ggplot2_3.2.1’ is not available (for R version 4.0.2)

I’m assuming I’ll need an earlier version of R, does anyone know which version? I went back to 3.4.3 but no luck (it was too early) and 4.1.0 is too late??

Answer (score 0):

I found the version combinations to get ggtern working again is:

R 4.0.2
ggplot2: 3.3.2
ggtern: 3.3.0 - ignore the warning...

Kind regards
Knighty16

Answer (score 0):

Try installing a version of R > 4.0, restarting your computer, and then rerunning the script. **ggtern** wouldn't work for me last year when I had R version 3.6. After the new install and a restart it works fine. If this isn't the issue, then there's a problem with your code. See examples below.

**install and load ggtern**

```
install.packages("ggtern")   
library(ggtern)
```

**recreate this simple plot** from http://www.ggtern.com/d/2.2.2/ggtern.html. If you don't get an output of the ternary plot with the data point in the center, you have version problems mentioned above.

```
ggtern(data=data.frame(x=1,y=1,z=1),aes(x,y,z)) + geom_point()
```

[ternary plot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O845W.png)

**create an example dataset for plotting.** Note that x + y + z often add up to > 1, indicating input data will be normalized automatically when using the ggtern plot function.

```
xdata <- c(64, 50, 50, 99)
ydata <- c(36, 50, 50,  1)
zdata <- c(19, 50,  0, 01)
df <- data.frame(xdata, ydata, zdata)
```

**plot the data and define aes in the ggtern call.** This is similar to ideal syntax for ggplot: https://community.rstudio.com/t/error-geom-point-requires-the-following-missing-aesthetics-x-y/26224.

```
plot <- ggtern(data = df, mapping = aes(x = xdata, y = ydata, z = zdata)) + geom_point() 
plot
```

[ternary plot example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqHFF.png)

You may also find guidance under the "ternary_transformation" header at this link if you want to transform data from cartesian to ternary space and vice-versa : http://www.ggtern.com/docs/.